# SwiftとPHP間の画像のやりとり

Tags: swift, php, cakephp, json

1. Swiftから画像をサーバサイド(PHP)に送信
2. PHPでは送られてきたデータをDBに保存
3. PHPでDBに保存されたデータを取り出して、Swift側に送信
4. Swift側ではPHPからの画像データを受け取って、UIImageViewに表示

画像のやりとりの勉強を兼ねて以上のような機能をもつ簡単なアプリの作成をしてます。
そこで幾つか問題が発生していて非常に困っています。

まず1→2なのですが、
SwiftからPHPではマルチパートのデータとしてPHP側に指定のURLで送信しています。

```
func uploadBtn(sender :UIButton){

    //POSTする画像を生成
    let sampleImage = UIImage(named: "images.jpg")
    let imageData:NSData = NSData(data:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(sampleImage!, 1.0)!)

    //NSURLRequestを生成
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.33.10/test_app/images/postImage")
    let urlRequest : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()

    if let u = url{
        urlRequest.URL = u
        urlRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        urlRequest.timeoutInterval = 30.0
    }

    //BODYを作成
    let uniqueId = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().globallyUniqueString
    let body: NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
    var postData :String = String()
    let boundary:String = "---------------------------\(uniqueId)"

    urlRequest.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") //(1)

    postData += "--\(boundary)\r\n"

    postData += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"images.jpg\"\r\n" //(2)
    postData += "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"
    body.appendData(postData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData(imageData)

    postData = String()
    postData += "\r\n"
    postData += "\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n"

    body.appendData(postData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!) //(3)

    urlRequest.HTTPBody = NSData(data:body)
    //print(urlRequest)

    //リクエストを送信してレスポンスを受け取る
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

    let task: NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: { data, request, error in

        //サーバサイドから返ってきたデータ
        let result = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        print("result=\(result)")
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

PHPでは

```
public function postImage(){
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){     
      $data = $_FILES['image'];
      /*　出力結果：
      array(5) {
            ["name"]=>
                 string(10) "images.jpg"
            ["type"]=>
                 string(10) "image/jpeg"
            ["tmp_name"]=>
                 string(14) "/tmp/phpWMcdjb"
            ["error"]=>
                 int(0)
            ["size"]=>
                 int(28051)
        }
      */
      $db =  mysql_connect('localhost','root','password');
      $table = mysql_select_db('test_db');
      $img = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];     
      $cont = file_get_contents($img)

  if($cont){
    //画像(バイナリデータ)を16進数に変換
     $img_binary = bin2hex($cont);

    if($table = mysql_query("insert into images (img_field) values ( ' ".$img_binary." ' )",$db)){
      //echo "画像をデータベースに保存しました。\n";
      $resp = true;
    }else{
      //echo "保存できませんでした。\n";
      echo "ERROR:".mysql_error()."\n";
      $resp = false;
    }
  } 
      //json形式でviewに吐く
      $this->set(compact('resp'));
      $this->viewClass = 'Json';
      $this->set('_serialize', array('resp'));
    }else{
      echo "not post";
    }
  }
```

imagesテーブルのimg_fieldにfile_get_contents()で読み込んだパスの内容($cont)を16進数に変換したデータ(バイナリデータままではなぜかDBに保存できなかったため16進数に変換)が保存されていることは確認しました。

ーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーー

2→3における
16進数に変換した画像データ（ $cont）をDBに保存し、それらJSONに埋め込んでをPHPからSwiftに送る部分は以下のようになっています。

```
public function recieveImage(){
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET"){

      $db =  mysql_connect('localhost','root','imagine');
      $table = mysql_select_db('test_db');
      $table = mysql_query("select img_field from images",$db);
      $array = $this->User->MMArray($table);
      var_dump($array);
      /*
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
               array(1) {
                 [0]=>
                    array(1) {
                      ["img_field"]=>
                                   string(16) " /tmp/phpz3Xoy2 "
                              }
                         }
                     }
      */
      $img = $array[0][0]["img_field"]; //$imgで16進数のデータを取得
      $resp = $img;
      //json形式でviewに吐く
      $this->set(compact('resp'));
      $this->viewClass = 'Json';
      $this->set('_serialize', array('resp'));
    }else{
      echo "not get";
    }
  }
```

Swift側では以下のようにしてJSONを受け取っています。

```
 func downloadBtn(sender :UIButton){

        //create url request
        //set URL
        let urlstr = "http://192.168.33.10/test_app/images/recieveImage"
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlstr)!)

        //set method
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

        //タスクの生成
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler:{ data, response, error in
            //succeed post
            if(error == nil){

                let json = JSON(data: data!)
                print("json=\(json)")
                /*
                    json={
                            "resp" : " 16進数に変換された画像データ "
                          }
                */

        }else{
            print(error)   
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Q:得られた16進数の画像データをSwiftで表示することができません。
16進数を本来の画像(バイナリ)データに変換し、それらを表示すればよいのではないかと思っているのですが...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

アップロードされた画像ファイルは $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] に入っているpathにファイルとして保存されています。
このファイルの内容をDBへ保存してください。

質問記載の場合、 /tmp/phpWMcdjb がアップロードされたファイル本体です。このファイルを読み込み、読み込んだ内容をDBへ保存してください。

Comment: ということは、$_FILES['image']['name']を保存するのではなく、$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] をDB保存し、それらをまたJSONでSwiftに送信すれば、また画像が表示可能になるということでよいのでしょうか？

Comment: $_FILES['image']['name']　にはクライアント側がアップロード時に指定したファイル名しかはいってません。JSON内に埋め込むか、画像に関しては別にしてContent-type:image/jpeg等で返すようにするか方法は様々なので好きな(実装しやすい)手法を選べばいいと思います。

Comment: この回答にマイナスモデ付けた理由が知りたい

Comment: $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] をDBに保存するのではなく、$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']に入っているpathのファイルの内容をDBに保存する必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。 $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] をJOSNに埋め込む方法で実装しようと思います。 
ちなみになのですが、DBに$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']を保存するフィールドは”mediumblob”でよいのでしょうか？

Comment: DBの項目の型はアップロードされるファイルの許容最大サイズをもとに決定してください。

Comment: もう一度書きます。　$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] をDBに保存するのではなく、$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']に入っているpathのファイルの内容をDBに保存する必要があります。

Comment: file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])で内容を取得すればよいのでしょうか。

Comment: はい。file_get_contents()で読み込み出来ます。

Comment: >この回答にマイナスモデ付けた理由が知りたい 
私はマイナスつけておりません。せっかく役立つ回答をしていただいているのに申し訳ないです。

投稿を編集いたしました。
今度はDBにパスのファイル内容を保存できていると思います。
ご確認いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 申し訳ありませんがswiftは守備範囲外なので私の助言はここまでとなります。一般的には文字列として保持している16進数文字列をバイナリーに変換をする処理を行います。